# How to add multiple rows to a database using a HTML form (Laravel)

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

On my user registration page I have a form where they fill out their name, email etc. I will be adding achievements to the list of things they need to fill out. However, I want the users to be able to put in as many achievements as they want. I will later be displaying these achievements on their profile page.

Here is my registration form as it is, if it helps.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/register/make" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('family_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Family Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="family_name" value="{{ old('family_name') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('family_name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('family_name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" value="{{ old('password') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('year') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Year Graduated</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="year" value="{{ old('year') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('year'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('year') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('mark') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Final Mark</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mark" value="{{ old('mark') }}">

                            @if ($errors->has('mark'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('mark') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Description</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{ old('description') }}">@if ($errors->has('description'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong>
                                </span>@endif</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('picture') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Upload a photo of yourself</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="picture">

                            @if ($errors->has('picture'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('picture') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                            <p>We recommend 300x300 pixels for best results.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                           <p>I agree to the <a href="/terms">terms and conditions</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button name="register" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    @if (count($errors))
                        <ul>
                            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li class="text-danger"> {{$error}} </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    @endif


                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use brackets in the field name, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="achievements[]"/>
```

Then with javascript/jquery, you can create more fields programmatically by providing a button for the user to add a new achievement.

Another option you can explore is using a library like [select2](https://select2.github.io/). It features [tagging](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags).

On the backend, PHP will convert the values to array. Then Laravel gives you access to this array from the Request, like so:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $achievements = $request->get('achievements');
}
```

From there you can iterate and save each achievement like you normally would.